# C++ Initialise base class

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble getting inheritance working.

I have a base class Entity with a derived class Item. I want to instantiate an Item with a name and description that will be passed back to the base class Entity. It's telling me:
"Constructor for ‘Item’ must explicitly initialise the base class ‘Entity’ which does not have a default constructor."

Here's how I'm trying to do it in the header:

```
Item(string name, string description): Entity(name, description){};
```

And the implementation:

```
Item::Item (string name, string description) {
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Are you sure Entity has a constructor implemented or defined with Entity::Entity(string name, string description)?

Comment: Wait I'm confused on your "header" and implementation poriton.. You are already implementing it in your header? Seems like if you either copy your header to your cpp, or remove your cpp one it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to reorder your code slightly.  The `: Entity(name, description)` part that passes the parameters to the base class's constructor should be part of the implementation of the constructor, not part of the declaration.

That is to say, the header should contain the bit

```
Item(string name, string description);
```

And the implementation should contain:

```
Item::Item (string name, string description): Entity(name, description) {
}
```

Comment: Well this may or may not be his solution.... You can certainly implement it the way he has in his header file (although not the best of practices). But he does also have an extra implementation in his cpp

Comment: Good point.  I was editing my post to say that I wasn't sure why the poster was getting an error about a default constructor and not an error about having 2 bodies for the 2 parameter version of the constructor when I caught your comment.  I guess if there was an error involving the default constructor, maybe it arises from other code not shown in the snippets from this question.